# Heat and hot water only gets warm on second floor

Tags: water-heater, boiler, hot-water

My heat and hot water only gets warm on the second floor. When I turn on my faucet and shower the water gets hot for a second then goes to warm also when I turn my heat on it takes a really long time for it to go up 2 degree. There is no problem on the first floor. I have a older boiler system in my house. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Tell us more. Is this a new problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.